# how to consume Odata Service from Android using any library that contain select where statement

Tags: android, sql, odata, restlet, odata4j

Is there a way to consume Odata Service from Android using Odata4j or any other library that contain SELECT WHERE Clause statement

I searched a lot but can't find any solution

Answer (score 0):

For odata4j you need to instantiate a ODataConsumer Object - let's call it consumer.
With this object you are able to perform any desired database actions.
For example:

```
OEntity result = consumer.getEntities("YourEntityName").filter("Field2 eq 'xyz'").select("Field1, Field2, Field3").execute();
```

This would resemble the following SQL query

```
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3 FROM YourEntityName WHERE Field2 = 'xyz'
```

For more information regarding the string arguments for filter() and select() you should have a look into the odata documentation at [odata.org](http://www.odata.org) -> URI conventions.

If you want to understand the java functions of odata4j use the documentation at [odata4j documentation](http://odata4j.org/v/0.7/javadoc/).

I can also recommend the [odata4j example files](https://code.google.com/p/odata4j/source/).

Comment: it works fine but what if I wanted query like this : SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3,Field 4 FROM EntityName1,EntityName2 WHERE Field2 = 'xyz' I made another statement like OEntity result = consumer.getEntities("EntityName2").select("Field4").execute(); but of course it didn't work as I want as by logic it did't contain the relation between EntityName1,EntityName1 represnted in Field2 as a KEY between the two entities .

Comment: Thanks , for my final question , I found this

https://code.google.com/p/odata4j/issues/attachmentText?id=30&aid=2700512303282867111&name=NorthwindConsumerExample.java&token=0d2faaa992f33d4d6289279b067a9d03

Answer (score 0):

Nice question......

We can access the odata service by using AsyncHttpClient in android.

Here we need to override some methods ,and its taking RequestParams as a parameter will return data as json or xml.

you can read more on AsyncHttpClient Here :http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

here we can pass RequestParams,it will take select as key and query as your original query.
try it and let me know if you have any issues